# How to remove single quotation marks in a column on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I remove the single quotation mark for the columns Genre and Country in my dataframe?

```
         ID                    Title                Type    Year  Released   Genre          Country
0   ts300399    Five Came Back: The Reference Films SHOW    1945    48     'documentary'      'US'
```

I tried strip() but didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Select the columns of interest and replace the punctuations by ""

```
df[['Genre','Country']] = df[['Genre','Country']].replace({"$^'|'": ""}, regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df[['Genre', 'Country']] = df[['Genre', 'Country']].apply(lambda col: col.str.strip("'"))
```

```
print(df)

   ID     Title                                      Type  Year  Released        Genre Country
0   0  ts300399  Five Came Back: The Reference Films SHOW  1945        48  documentary      US
```

Comment: `.applymap(lambda x: x.strip("'"))` ~ May be slightly faster~

Answer (score 0):

```
df[['Genre','Country']] = df[['Genre','Country']].replace({"^'|'$": ""}, regex=True)
```

**Edit**

The `.replace` method seems to be slighlty faster than the `.apply()` + `.strip()` one:

[image]

Comment: What if some value is `'test's'`?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, good point! Even if OP didn't mention it,  I have updated the regex accordingly :)

Comment: Take a much larger dataframe, and you'll see that the replace method is actually far slower. `df = pd.concat([df]*100000)` .... `replace()` method = `339ms`, ... `strip()` method = `45.1ms`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the single quotes are always present:

```
df[['Genre', 'Country']] = df[['Genre', 'Country']].applymap(lambda x: x[1:-1])
```

Would get the job done and be very fast.